# Api recebe data com mês e dia trocados se o parâmetro for enviado pela url

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Tenho uma api que recebe uma data (a data é enviada como string e recebida como DateTime):

```
    [HttpPost("ObterDados")]
    public JsonResult ObterDados(DateTime data)
    {
       //codigo
```

se eu fizer o post com o parâmetro na url a data é recebida com o mês e dia invertidos (recebe mm/dd/yyyy)

```
    $.post("/api/ObterDados/?data=" + self.Data...
```

se eu enviar a data dentro de um objeto ela é recebida corretamente (recebe dd/mm/yyyy)

```
    var objeto = {data: "15/12/2017"}

    $.post("/api/ObterDados/", objeto....

    [HttpPost("ObterDados")]
    public JsonResult ObterDados(Filtro filtro)
    {
       //codigo
```

Por que isso acontece e tem algum modo de sempre receber a data como dd/mm/yyyy ?

Obs: A data sempre é enviada como string

Configuração da classe Statup:

```
        var requestLocalizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {

            SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("pt-BR")
            },
            SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("pt-BR")
            },

            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pt-BR", "pt-BR"),
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions);
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
      </handlers>
      <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: De uma olhada nesta pergunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690879/how-use-a-specific-cultureinfo-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: Basta configurar o CultureInfo no seu WebConfig

Comment: Com essa configuração o Binder vai fazer o DateTime.Parse na cultura default da aplicação, ou seja, o que estiver configurado no config. Se quiser você pode fazer isso via código, mas acho mais eficiente fazer isso na Config.

Comment: Coloquei a configuração da classe Startup(asp.net core 2.0) na pergunta, da uma olhada, seria a mesma coisa que fazer isso que você sugeriu no webconfig ?

Comment: Puxa, é diferente no .net core?

Comment: Acho que sim, desde que criei o projeto não alterei o web.config, nem pra conexão com o banco..

Comment: Deve ter a <Globalization> no web.config não vejo motivo para não ter :-\

Comment: Dá uma olhada na resposta aceita lá, ele coloca no Web.Config, porque pelo Web.Config você fala com o IIS eu não vejo motivo para o .net core ter modificado isso.

Comment: Vou tentar a solução da resposta aceita, coloquei o web.config do projeto na pergunta..

Comment: Da uma olhada, versão Core de Globalization https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization

Comment: Mande como YYYY-MM-DD, que é um formato não-ambíguo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após seguir Vários tutoriais, ter tentado de diversas formas corrigir isso configurando a aplicação, a melhor opção foi criar um componente utilizando vue.js, para inputs que forem data.
Ele formata a data em dd/mm/yyyy na tela mas no valor a data esta com o formato yyyy/mm/dd. Assim não preciso usar funções cada vez que envio a data para a api.